# R Changing default values with formals() does not work for sort()

Tags: r, default-value

I realised that using `formals(sort)$decreasing <- TRUE` does not change the default value as I expected, whereas `formals(sample)$replace <- TRUE` does its job.

To reproduce the problem:

```
# does not work
sort(1:5)
formals(sort)$decreasing <- TRUE
sort(1:5)
args(sort)  # default apparently changed correctly, but output did not

# works fine
sample(1:2, 3)
formals(sample)$replace <- TRUE
sample(1:2, 3)
```

I'm curious why formals() apparently only works for some functions and how I would change the default values!

I use R 3.4.2

Comment: I don't know, but ... that type of change has the side-effect of making your code not completely reproducible, analogous to setting `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`. It will work for you, but if you give somebody code that looks like `sort(sample(5))`, it will appear (per your code) that it should sort them with `decreasing=FALSE` (the default). Being explicit takes a few more key-presses but is more portable. Just my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your response and I partly agree! However I am interested in a proper way to change formals in a code!

Comment: Re @r2evans critique, we could consider a more transparent approach: `mysort = sort; formals(mysort)[["decreasing"]] = TRUE; mysort(1:5)` -- still runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `sort()`, unlike `sample()`, is a generic function in R. If you type just `sort` without the parenthesis, you can see that it calls the `useMethod()` which is how it triggers the S3 generic behavior. The code there doesn't actually get "run", it just launches the correct version of sort depending on the class of the object you pass to it. You can do this, however

```
sort(1:5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
formals(sort.default)$decreasing <- TRUE
sort(1:5)
# [1] 5 4 3 2 1
```

Of course it's a terrible idea in general to change the behavior of built in functions. And really this is making a shadow copy of `sort()` with the different settings in your global environment. The original sort would still be available at

```
base::sort.default(1:5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```